# Login loop and black screen when using graphics card

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, graphics, xorg, intel-graphics

### How i got here

I have been using Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop with an Nvidia GTX 1660Ti card with the 440 driver installed using the .run file downloaded from Nvidia's site. I need it for pytorch cuda acceleration and running some simulations on gazebo.

My system setup :

- i7 9750H with integrated GPU
- Nvidia Geforce GTX 1660Ti (with optimus support)
- 16GB RAM
- Ubuntu 18.04 on dual boot with Windows 10
- x86_64 Linux 5.4.0-52-generic kernel

The issues started when i did a BIOS update. First, the brightness was on max and the slider did not change it. The mousepad too stopped working. I tried installing `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`, following some instructions on the forums, and it ended up removing some xserver-xorg packages and ubuntu-desktop. Rebooting the system resulted in a black screen with a lot of text starting with [OK]. I could start tty with alt+ctr+F2 but could not login because the earlier black screen kept flashing in between and captured my keystrokes. I changed display manager to lightdm and was able to start tty. I uninstalled the nvidia drivers and added nomodeset and installed `ubuntu-desktop` and `xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04` was able to login, and everything works fine. But, i cannot use my GPU (integrated or discrete, both).

### The issue

However, when i remove nomodeset, even when running on the integrated GPU, i go into a **login loop**. The lightdm login screen shows up, then my wallpaper shows up and stays for about 2 seconds, then goes back to the login screen. Permissions and ownership of /tmp folder and .Xauthority file is not a problem. I tried installing nvidia drivers, which resulted in a black screen (no login screen). Adding nomodeset works fine, but i obviously cannot use my nvidia GPU for cuda acceleration, nor can i load gazebo, and hence is not an option in the long term.

I am a beginner in linux and know very little about the kernel, display management, etc. So, i was not able to effectively find any problems in the /var/log/Xorg.0.log file. Please guide me on what could be the problem, and ask which log files i need to attach (please use full paths if possible because i really dont know my way here)

Output of `apt list --installed | grep xserver`

```
x11-xserver-utils/bionic,now 7.7+7build1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-common/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,now 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.7 all [installed]
xserver-xephyr/bionic-updates,now 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.7 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.2~18.04.3 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04/bionic-updates,now 1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04/bionic-updates,now 1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04/bionic-updates,now 0.28.1-1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-18.04/bionic-updates,now 1:0.36.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-18.04/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.2~18.04.3 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-18.04/bionic-updates,now 1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04/bionic-updates,now 19.1.0-1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-18.04/bionic-updates,now 1:19.1.0-1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-18.04/bionic-updates,now 1:0.5.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04/bionic-updates,now 2:2.99.917+git20171229-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04/bionic-updates,now 1:1.0.16-1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-18.04/bionic-updates,now 0.1.5-2build2~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04/bionic-updates,now 1:19.1.0-1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-18.04/bionic-updates,now 1:2.4.0-1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-18.04/bionic-updates,now 1:13.3.0-2build1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
```

Output of `sudo lshw -C display`

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:b2000000-b207ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b5000000-b5ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```